# Saying something rude about someone to someone else while they're present

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I need a colloquial expression (not a term) that can be used when someone indirectly says something annoying to provoke someone standing next to them.

For example, me and Hannah fought angrily and stopped talking. The next day we met in a gathering. I was standing with someone else and Hannah was next to me, then I say something rude or malicious about Hannah to that person so that I provoke her, knowing that she is standing next to me.

Comment: There are many.  Can you give more details about the context?  Is the insult *deliberate*?  Is it especially *nasty* or *mean-spirited*?

Comment: Are you talking about an expression to describe the person, what they said, the event itself, or what?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on your phrasing. You said when someone "indirectly" says something "to provoke". Indirectly implies it was an accident, but saying something "to provoke" implies intent. Is the person trying to upset the other person, or not?

Comment: "They stepped in it"? This means they did not mean to, but they stepped into the excrement (sh*t).

Comment: @Andrew  Yes it is deliberate. I'm gonna give you an example. Like,  me and Hannah fought angrily and stopped talking. The next day we met in a gathering. I was standing with someone else and Hannah was next to me, then I say something rude or malicious about Hannah to that person so that I provoke her, knowing that she is standing next to me. You get me?

Comment: @NathanTuggy please see my comment

Comment: It is deliberate. I'm gonna give you an example. Like,  me and Hannah fought angrily and stopped talking. The next day we met in a gathering. I was standing with someone else and Hannah was next to me, then I say something rude or malicious about Hannah to that person so that I provoke her, knowing that she is standing next to me. You get me?

Comment: @WillowRex It is deliberate. I'm gonna give you an example. Like,  me and Hannah fought angrily and stopped talking. The next day we met in a gathering. I was standing with someone else and Hannah was next to me, then I say something rude or malicious about Hannah to that person so that I provoke her, knowing that she is standing next to me. You get me?

Comment: @Dana, thanks for the update.  There is a phrase for this, but darned if I can't think of it ...

Comment: Dana: As @Andrew says, there are many possibilities. See synonyms of [***annoy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/irritate), vex, make angry, make cross, anger, exasperate, bother, irk, gall, pique, put out, displease, get someone's back up, etc.* For an informal context, I'd be very likely to use metaphoric *I knew that would **rattle her cage*** or ***...wind her up***, but there are *so* many alternatives (colloquial and "formal") that it's not really possible to expect a single unambiguously "correct" answer here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think annoy, irk ...etc. are a little general, I thought there might be something more specific, but thank you !

Comment: You're right that ***irk, annoy*** are far more "general", in that a mindless insect or an inanimate object could irk/annoy you. But ***provoke*** (or my two idiomatic colloquialisms) almost always have the precise meaning ***deliberately** do something **specifically** because you know it will annoy someone*, as do many other expressions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I liked 'rattle her cage'. Wrote them down, thanks alot :)

Comment: There's also ***needle***, which will work in many contexts. But I'm not convinced there will be any single word (or even short expression) that unambiguously conveys that the *way* you wound her up / rattled her cage / needled her was by saying things to someone else in a "stage whisper" (i.e. - knowing that ***she*** would hear you too, as well as whoever you were *apparently* talking to).

Comment: I also think that *provoke* is a great word. The OP (Dana) used it and it works perfectly. However "me and Hannah" is better put as: "Hannah and I" or, "We fought".

Comment: @WillowRex I couldn't use 'we' at the beginning, but yes Hannah and I would have been more correct. Thanks for the remark Willow!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I searched the word 'needle' and liked its meaning: to annoy or provoke someone by continuously questioning or criticizing them. Such words can be used a lot in everyday life!

Comment: @Dana: In your *exact* context (where the person you're trying to provoke is within earshot, but you're not directly addressing them), it stands to reason you'll be referring to them in the third person (using ***she/her*** rather than ***you***). If the situation were to be reversed (i.e. - *she's* talking about *you*), then a good way to assert yourself and express your annoyance would be [***Who's she - the cats mother?***](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38952/2637) as covered by that closely-related ELU question which you might find interesting (sadly, it only works for women! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various phrases for this: "catty remark", "snide aspersion", "barbed remark", "subtle dig", etc.  None of these indicate the other person is *in earshot*, but you can include that information in the sentence:

> While talking to her friend, Dana *snidely insulted* Hanna's character, after making sure Hanna was close enough to *overhear*.

Comment: I think those are the closest to what I'm looking for. Thank you Andrew!

Comment: @Dana  If I think of any better, I'll add them to my answer.  I'm sure there's a better phrase, but as we say, "it's on the tip of my tongue..."

Comment: no problem, those could do! Till there's a better phrase :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a colloquial expression that exactly captures the situation you described in the comments.

I understand that to be:

> Person A is angry at Person B. Person A starts saying bad things about Person B to Person C, with the intention of provoking them.

The closest thing I can think of is that we'd call something like that

> Passive-aggressive behavior

Whereby you are not directly attacking a person, but doing things to intentionally upset them. It covers a broad variety of behaviors, not just this. For example, if I were upset with a work colleague, and I ignore their requests for important work documents. I am not doing anything *to* them, but my *passive* behavior is *aggressively* hurting them.

So in your example, I would say that you were

> "Being passive-aggressive to Hannah"

Comment: I'd hardly say ***passive-aggressive behavior*** is a "colloquial" usage. Per Wikipedia, it's the actual terminology used in the [Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive-aggressive_behavior)

Comment: I didn't imply it was colloquial, and I think the first sentence of my post clearly pointed out I couldn't think of one that totally encompassed the situation. Therefore I came up with a word or phrase that I felt would *most nearly* do that. And it is a phrase that is in common use, that the average person would likely understand.

Comment: My apologies. Dunno how I failed to take in the first three words of your answer. I'll remove my slapdash downvote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not at all, its fine.